# Apache web server and virtual host can not be accessed from other Ubuntu pc in LAN

Tags: apache2

From server PC (same pc), I am able to access Apache web server using this link http://192.168.0.21 and virtual host 50000SiteName using this link http://192.168.0.21/50000SiteName

But I am not able to access above links from different Ubuntu pc in LAN.

Similarly I am able to connect to virtual host in dreamweaver from same server PC but not able to connect to that virtual host from different Ubuntu pc in LAN using same settings.

I guess I may need to do some other settings in Apache web server to make this possible but not sure what they are so please let me know what I am missing and what settings I should do.

Below are OS and Web Server details

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Apache version 2.4.7

Below code mentioned in **etc/apache2/apache2.conf** file

- ServerName 192.168.0.21

Below code mentioned in **etc/apache2/port.conf** file

- NameVirtualHost *:80
- Listen *:80

'50000SiteName' virtualhost is created under Apache web server. and it's config file **etc/apache2/sites-avaiable/50000SiteName.conf** contains below code.

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/50000SiteName
    ServerName 192.168.0.21
    <Directory /var/www>
        allow from all
        Options None
    </Directory>
    <Directory var/www/50000SiteName>
        allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Options None
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First from clientPc check if the port 80 is open

```
nmap -p 80 -PN 192.168.0.21
```

If it's not open and you're using ufw firewall, allow connections from inside your lan with

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 80
```

Test again the port is open

```
nmap -p 80 -PN 192.168.0.21
```

Then edit the `<Directory>` part as follow (it works for me)

```
<Directory /var/www/50000SiteName>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Ty and I will check all these things and will let you know.

Comment: nmap has given this result: host is up (80/tcp filtered http)... I also made Directory changes mentioned above still not working yet...

Comment: Filtered is not open, did you open the port on ufw?

Comment: Check the `Directory` config again, i made an edit because the / at the begining was missing

Comment: I enabled ufw and opened port 80 and 21. Now I am able to connect to Apache server virtual host from other PCs in LAN. But there is one small issue that from other PCs I am not able to add/edit files in website folder in dreamweaver. I guess it is permission related issue but not sure what permissions are needed for it. Can you please advise on this too? Ty

Comment: it's been ages since i dont use dreamweaver, how are you accessing the server files, ftp? ssh? nfs?

Comment: yes... Dreamweaver accesses server files using FTP.

Comment: add the ftp user to `www-data` group,  which is able to write on apache web root and below

Comment: I have added ftpuser to www-data group using this command (sudo usermod -a -G www-data ftpuser) but it is still not working. I also tried to set user (ftpuser) and group (www-data) for Apache web server using webmin but still no luck.

Comment: you didnt mention webmin, i think webmin has its own way of doing things. Now you have to check the owner and group of the dir that you want to access, and match the group and/or ftpuser, and give write permissions to group if necessary, because obviously you have read permissions.

Comment: sudo chown -R www-data:ftpuser /var/www - this command resolved the issue of permission. Now it is working.